# Let $\tau = \left \{\left \{ 1,..., n \right \}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right \}\cup \mathbb{N} \cup \emptyset$. Prove $\tau$ is a Topology for $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau = \left \{\left \{ 1,..., n \right \}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right \}\cup \mathbb{N} \cup \emptyset$. Prove $\tau$ is a Topology for $\mathbb{N}$

I have proved the two of the three properties needed to be a topology but I need help proving that the arbitrary union of opens in $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$. I have problems proving it because I don´t know how to show there exist a bigger one set containing all the others, that is, there exists a $n$ greater than the other, but I think if I say it then $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded set. So there must be another way to prove it is a topology

Answer (score 2):

Say $\{A_{i}\}\subset\tau$. Just consider some possible cases.

If $A_{j}=\mathbb{N}$ for some $j$, then clearly $\bigcup A_{i}=\mathbb{N}\in\tau$.

If not, you have two subcases to consider.

Case 1: You have infinitely many $A_{i}$. In this case, $\bigcup A_{i}=\mathbb{N}$, for otherwise, if $n\notin\bigcup A_{i}$, it follows that no $A_{j}$ equals $\{1, \ldots, m\}$ for any $m\geq n$. In other words, you can't have infinitely many $A_{i}$.

Case 2: You have finitely many $A_{i}$. Say $A_{i}=\{1,\ldots,n_{i}\}$. Then, $\bigcup A_{i}=\{1,\ldots N\}$, where $N$ is the max of the $n_{i}$'s.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a set $I$ is an element in the topology iff for all $k\in {\Bbb N}$:
$$ k\in I \Rightarrow \{1,...,k\} \subset I$$
And you verify that this property is preserved under arbitrary unions.